# Is it possible to reference a property value?

Tags: css

There is a property :

```
td { width : 200px; }
```

I want to write another css property , and the value of that property is the same as the previous one because I want to make them **always** the same value :

```
li.dropdown2 ul { width: 200px; }
```

So is it possible to reference the value of the property of the element td inside the second property ?

Comment: Like: `td, li.dropdown2 ul { width: 200px; }` ?

Comment: the problem is they are in separate files !

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible using CSS.

However, tools like SCSS/SASS or LESS let you define variables which you can then use in both places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit):

```
li.dropdown2 ul { width: inherit; }
```

Which inherits the value from it's parent.

Comment: It is far away from the td element !